# sum function not working

Tags: python, list, sum, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a program that sums the integers in the odd columns of a list

```
def sum_of_odd_cols(x):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        odds=[x[k][j] for k in range(len(x)) if j%2!=0]
    return sum(odds)

x=[[1,2,5],[3,4,6],[7,8,9]]
print(sum_of_odd_cols(x))
```

What I get from this is '0', why is this happening?

Also one more question

```
x=[[1,2,5],[3,4,6],[7,8,9]]
for j in range(len(x)):
    col=[column[j] for column in x]
```

this also seems to create a list of the columns in list x, however I don't understand how this works
is 'column' a built in function in python?

Comment: Sample input and expected output would be nice.

Comment: The reason it returns `0` is because your `odds` array is empty.

Comment: Reassigning `odds` or `col` on every iteration of the loop does not do what you want to do.

Comment: There's also something wrong with the `odds=[x[k][j] for k in range(len(x)) if j%2!=0]` bit. I don't think that's what you want to do.

Comment: As for the second thing, `column` is not a built-in function. It's the iteration variable of the list comprehension; see the `for column in x` part. I suggest you read up on how the Python `for` loop works. range-len iteration like what your first snippet uses is almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
x = [[1,2,5],[3,4,6],[7,8,9]]    # Generate the list
sum([sum(k[1::2]) for k in x])   # Sum the numbers in odd columns
# 14
```

if you need the *combined* sum for all the numbers in the odd columns.

Comment: Wouldn't this sum the even columns (indices) instead of the odd ones?

Comment: Gotta love Sunday morning pre-coffee time.

Comment: IT runs on coffee. No doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]])

b = np.sum(a[:,::2], axis=0)   # column 0, 2, ...
# b = [2, 6]
b = np.sum(a[:,::2])
# b = 8

c = np.sum(a[:,1::2], axis=0)  # column 1, 3, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def sum_of_odd_cols(x):
    oddsum = 0
    for j in range(len(x)):
        oddsum += sum([x[k][j] for k in range(len(x)) if j%2!=0])
    return oddsum

x=[[1,2,5],[3,4,6],[7,8,9]]
print(sum_of_odd_cols(x))
```

This probably isn't the best way of doing it, but it will get your code working. The odds variable was getting overwritten by a new list in each iteration of the loop, and since the final column was empty (it's index is even), the sum was always 0.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it returns `0` is because your `odds` array is empty at the end of the for loop; because in each iteration of the loop you are resetting `odds`. If you write your loop the 'long' way, it will return the correct results:

```
odds = []
for j in range(len(x)):
   for k in range(len(x)):
      if j % 2 != 0:
         odds.append(x[k][j])
```

If I add some print statements, this is what happens:

```
j is: 0
k is: 0
k is: 1
k is: 2
j is: 1
k is: 0
Adding: 2 to odds
k is: 1
Adding: 4 to odds
k is: 2
Adding: 8 to odds
j is: 2
k is: 0
k is: 1
k is: 2
>>> odds
[2, 4, 8]
```

For the second part of your question:

> Also one more question
>
> x=[[1,2,5],[3,4,6],[7,8,9]] for j in range(len(x)):
>       col=[column[j] for column in x]
>
> this also seems to create a list of the columns in list x, however I
>   don't understand how this works is 'column' a built in function in
>   python?

No, this is a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), a short-hand way of constructing lists.

The loop is actually:

```
col = []
for column in x:
   col.append(column[j])
```

Where `j` is some other variable (set above the comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

Your first question has been answered various times.

As for your second question, think about unzipping your nested list (supposing it is not ragged):

```
>>> x=[[1,2,5],[3,4,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [x for x in zip(*x)]
[(1, 3, 7), (2, 4, 8), (5, 6, 9)]
```

This gives you a list containing the columns.

If the tuples are a problem and you need lists inside the list, use the builtin `list`:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*x)]
[[1, 3, 7], [2, 4, 8], [5, 6, 9]]
```

So basically your two questions boil down to this:

```
def sum_of_odd_cols(x):
    return sum(sum(x[1::2]) for x in x)

def rows_to_columns(x):
    return [list(x) for x in zip(*x)]
```